# delete course in Open EDX Ironwood version

Tags: openedx

I'm using the Ironwood Open Edx version and I don't see any buttons to delete a course

How to delete a course in Open EDX?

Are there any scripts or something similar to delete the course?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

go to edx-platform directory:

`cd /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform`

run this command and get all of your course ids:

`sudo -u www-data /edx/bin/python.edxapp /edx/bin/manage.edxapp lms dump_course_ids --settings production`

remove course, based on their id by this command:

`sudo -u www-data /edx/bin/python.edxapp /edx/bin/manage.edxapp cms delete_course COURSE_ID --settings production`

Comment: I think settings should not be "aws" for Ironwood. I think it should be "production".